# How to reset telegram on Ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, telegram

After receiving a sticker in a secret chat, telegram crashed. At each attempt to open it again, it crashed again. I reinstalled telegram and rebooted the phone, to no avail.

This was on OTA-13. Telegram 2.2.30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. open terminal application
2. run `rm -rf ~/.config/com.ubuntu.telegram` and `rm -rf ~/.cache/com.ubuntu.telegram` **This will delete your secret chats**

Alternatively, you can delete these directories in the file manager, after enabling `show hidden files`. (thanks pomsky)

Comment: Isn't removing the config enough? Are you sure it is necessary to uninstall/install Telegram?

Comment: @CelticWarrior Not sure if uninstalling and reinstalling telegram was necessary . I modified my answer accordingly. Cache was necessary to delete though.

Comment: @CelticWarrior  uninstalling and reinstalling telegram was not necessary . I modified my answer accordingly. The behavior is reproducible

Comment: deleting those directories using the file manager also works